# The probability of my winning?

Tags: probability

Let us assume that,  Me and My Cousin have started a game (Its Dice, the winner will be, who puts the six of the dice first ). There are  6 digits on the dice (1, 2 , 3  , 4,  5 , 6). 6 is the wining digit.  If I throw the dice first, then what is the probability that I will win. (thy way we  threw  the dice like  Me **Cousin** Me **Cousin** Me ... infinite)

If I won at the first time then the probability would be  1/6. But I would not get have a chance to win at the first throw!

Comment: Your question is quite unclear. Would you mind clarifying?

Comment: What have you tried?  Might be easier to start with coin tosses (winner being first to throw H).  Easy to write out all possibilities for 4 tosses or so...  Or just try the game and get a numerical estimate.

Comment: @Gummybears -  I think he means "Players #1 and #2 take turns throwing a fair die.  Winner is first one to throw a 6. Find the probability that #1 wins the game."

Comment: The possibility of throwing is infinity , therefore i think $\frac{a}{n-r}$ would work. I am not sure.

Comment: I guess... But I was trying to understand what he had tried on the question, which I suppose is given by the last line.. @lulu

Comment: @Gummybears, yes right you are!

Comment: @SabbirHasan.  True...in theory the tosses might go on forever. But that is a probability 0 event.  Try it (with the coins!  using the die will take too long).  If you get a very long string of T's there's something wrong with your coin.

Answer (score 1):

Hint #1: Try to turn your problem into a geometric series.

Hint #2: There's a bit of factoring to be done.

Edit: Hint #3: You can win on either the turn number $1, 3, 5, ...$ - add up all these probabilities.

Comment: But, don't we have the same probability of  the all  turns?

Comment: The probability of winning on each turn *given that you've reached that turn* is 1/6. But it becomes less and less likely that you reach a particular turn the further out you go, because the chances are someone will have won already. So maybe the best way of thinking about this is to separate your concerns: 1) What's the probability of reaching a turn? 2) What's the probability of winning *given* that you've reached a turn. This leads to an infinite sum. However, Ofir Schnabel's solution is much slicker.

Answer (score 1):

As you said, you will start throwing the dice first. So the probability that you will win on the first throw will be $\frac{1}{6}$
Now, consider that you don't win on the first throw. The probability of this happening is $x$. Now for you to win on your next throw, it is necessary for your cousin to lose on her throw, probability being $x$. So the possibility for you to win on your second throw (third throw overall in the game) is $x * x * \frac{1}{6}$
Continue writing for further tosses, and you will notice a pattern starting to emerge. Your overall probability of winning will simply by the sum.

Comment: This means   x^n *(1/6) = 1 ?

Comment: Why are you equating it with 1?

Comment: @SabbirHasan Did you try calculating the probability of you winning on your third toss?

Answer (score 1):

I think that there is a very simple (and maybe wrong) solution to this problem.

Denote the probability that the first thrower to win by $x$.
Then the second thrower has probability $1-x$.

But it is clear that the probability of the second thrower is just the probability of the first thrower to miss (not throwing $6$) in the first throw, times $x$.

From here
$$1-x=\frac{5}{6}x\Rightarrow x=\frac{6}{11}.$$

Comment: I have not got  that how  the probability of the second thrower is  5/6 * x

Comment: @SabbirHasan there is a $\frac{5}{6}$ probability that the first thrower will miss. If he indeed misses, the you can think about the second thrower as the "new" first thrower, and hence his probability is $x$.